# Heroku Spring Redis - SessionDestroyedEvent

Tags: heroku, redis, spring-session

In Spring, SessionDestroyedEvent is emitted based on redis notify-keyspace-events, which are disabled in Heroku: https://help.heroku.com/5BP0E8RC/how-to-enable-notify-keyspace-events-on-redis

The Spring doc only mentiones the 'configure' command (which is disabled in Heroku): https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#api-redisoperationssessionrepository-sessiondestroyedevent

Is there a workaround to receive SessionDestroyedEvent events on Heroku, using Redis?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the solution Heroku recommends using SUBSCRIBE and PSUBSCRIBE would mean heavily reconfiguring the default Spring Session configuration.

I had the same problem you have now, and decided to opt for [redislabs](https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise/cloud/cloud-pricing/). You can get started for free and if you're using Spring Boot, you can enjoy the ease of autoconfiguration, as there are no restrictions that would require writing workarounds.